# Origin of “I’ve heard of [x] but this is ridiculous!”

Tags: etymology, phrases, jokes

I heard this on a David Frost show from the 60s. It’s got me wondering who was the first comedian to use this joke form.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ButThisIsRidiculous

Comment: Etymology may sometimes seem like Trivial Pursuit but that is not in itself cause for closevote. Lack of research however ...

Comment: @MετάEd: Etymology is about word origins. This Q is about "Who's the first comedian to use this joke form?" The OED might show the first printed usage of the expression _ButThisIsRidiculous_, but the words are all common enough to find the etymologies in a good college dictionary. Quite a different kettle of lexemes, I'd say.

Comment: @MετάEd The research was "I googled for the answer but couldn't find it."  Couldn't that be said of every question on this site?

Comment: @user21497 Surely etymology also concerns phrase origins!

Answer (score 4):

Groucho Marx used to use this phrase. For example, in *A Night in Casablanca* his character said, “I’ve seen five o’clock shadow, but this is ridiculous!” Don’t know if it originated with him or not, though.

Comment: +1 There are no examples of this formulaic expression in literature (Google Book Search) until after that 1946 movie. The earliest: *The first guy said, "You mean Bob Hope followed us all the way to Bizerte? I volunteered to serve my country, but this is ridiculous."* (*Modern radio advertising*, Funk & Wagnalls Co. in association with Printers' Ink Pub. Co., 1953)